# Anyone experiencing weird behavior of "wire"?

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

Been learning Salesforce for a month now and this is the first weird stuff I have encountered and not a single documentation was able to help me

I have imported the **wire** from **lwc** properly

But whenever I'm deploying it, it says that a **wire variable** is **NOT** a known adapter, can anyone kindly help me out to resolve this please?

[image: Weird behavior]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So dumb of me, the official documentation wasn't able to tell that I need to import some important tools

Aside from importing **wire**, we'll need the following:

```
import { publish, MessageContext } from 'lightning/messageService';
```

take note of this, especially those who want to use the LMS, or to communicate their component to another component that's not related at all

Answer (score 0):

You should have received an error in your IDE when you made this mistake.

> c:\Users\brian\workspace\sfdcfox\recordEditorComponent.js: LWC1100: Invalid decorator usage. Supported decorators (api, wire, track) should be imported from "lwc"lwc

[image: Invalid wire adapter screenshot]

It seems like you haven't fully set up your environment/missed some steps. In your terminal/command line system, you should probably take the following steps:

```
sfdx force:project:create -n myProjectName
cd myProjectName
npm i
```

The entire transaction should look something like this:

```
brian@home MINGW64 ~/workspace
$ sfdx force:project:create -n myProject
target dir = C:\Users\brian\workspace
   create myProject\config\project-scratch-def.json
   create myProject\README.md
   create myProject\sfdx-project.json
   create myProject\.husky\pre-commit
   create myProject\.vscode\extensions.json
   create myProject\.vscode\launch.json
   create myProject\.vscode\settings.json
   create myProject\force-app\main\default\lwc\.eslintrc.json
   create myProject\force-app\main\default\aura\.eslintrc.json
   create myProject\scripts\soql\account.soql
   create myProject\scripts\apex\hello.apex
   create myProject\.eslintignore
   create myProject\.forceignore
   create myProject\.gitignore
   create myProject\.prettierignore
   create myProject\.prettierrc
   create myProject\jest.config.js
   create myProject\package.json


brian@home MINGW64 ~/workspace
$ cd myProject

brian@home MINGW64 ~/workspace/myProject
$ npm i

> salesforce-app@1.0.0 postinstall
> husky install

fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

added 756 packages, and audited 757 packages in 24s

104 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

brian@home MINGW64 ~/workspace/myProject
$
```

By following these steps, you'll ensure that you're getting the full developer experience.

Regardless, this error is incorrect. I'm going to try and contact someone in Salesforce to see if we can get this message corrected. It should state something about how MessageContext isn't a known adapter, which would be a clue that you forgot to import something.

In general, whenever you see "X is not a known adapter", it means that you have forgotten to import the adapter. This is true for both Salesforce development and [LWC OSS](https://lwc.dev/).

Comment: Hello sir @sfdcfox! Thank you for such an insightful and detailed answer! I already figured it out as what I have answered above this. It's just that the official documentation wasn't able to explain that we need to import the `MessageContext` tool from the `'lightning/messageService'`